# Exceptions are logged to localhost.log instead of the file specified in logback config

Tags: slf4j, logback

I have **SLF4J 1.7.7** and **logback-classic 1.1.2** in a web app deployed to **tomcat 8.0.8** on **Java 8**
Some of my logs properly go to the FileAppender I configured in the `logback.xml`, others though go to tomcat's `localhost.yyyy-MM-dd.log`
This behaviour is very annoying during development and will be unacceptable in the production environment.

Here is the logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="fileappender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/tomcat/mywebapp.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>mywebapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="async" class="reactor.logback.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="fileappender"/>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="async"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is using Apache's **commons-logging** library for logging. Same goes for a wide variety of open source libraries (for instance **spring**). There are other libraries which handle their logging with **log4j**.

In case you want to log all of your logging output via slf4j (and in your case logback), you'll probably have to use slf4j bridges (**jcl-over-slf4j** and **log4j-over-slf4j** for **commons-logging** and **log4j** respectively).

Check the logging sources in tomcat's localhost.yyyy-MM-dd.log file to find out what is the actual logging library and check if the problem is fixed by placing the related slf4j bridge
on the classpath.

Keep in mind that the actual logging dependency (log4j or commons-logging jars) **should not** be on classpath along with the corresponding bridge.

Comment: I do have jcl-over-slf4j in my <dependencies> and it is indeed copied into the war's libs.

Comment: Please check if: 
1) commons-logging is in your war libs (it shouldn't be)
2) which particular logs end up in the tomcat's localhost.yyyy-MM-dd.log file.